# Over 60 Ubuntu noob dual booter seeks Win10 Ubuntu reallocation, long walks on short pier

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Hail penguins.

I am an ancient Dos / Windows veteran experimenting  with dual boot Ubuntu and seeking guidance on reallocating space on my HDD.

1) I'm running an older Acer Aspire with 500GB.  Currently 400GB or so allocated to Windows C:, about 20 GB allocated to Ubuntu root.

2) I just freed up 0.5 GB unallocated space on the "left" of my EFI, and 16GB on the "right" of my Ubuntu root allocation.  450GB of C: (45 % utilized) in the middle. So for all practical purposes (forgive rounding)
0.5GB unallocated
0.4GB EFI
429GB C:
20GB Ubuntu
16GB unallocated

3) I want to a) move the 0.5GB to the "right" end, b) combine it with the 16GB of unallocated space and c) make that available to Ubuntu for user directories.

Can all of this be done in Gparted or do I need to use MS Disk Management /other utilities to move the unallocated space on the "left" ?

Sorry for the poor language skills. Me talk pretty one day.

Pallama

Comment: "Long walk on a short dock" has a nicer ring to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the 16G on the right of the current  20G Ubuntu partition (and expanding the filesystem into the new space -- easy with gparted, even on a running system.

Moving every partition to the left, including the Windows partition, just to gain 500M, probably not worth the trouble and risk.  If you really want to use that space, just put a 500Mpartition there and make it someone's home directory or just some data storage space.  This partition may be mounted and will appear to just add usable space -- low risk.

Comment: Thanks ubfan1. I expanded the Ubuntu partition to add the 16GB and that worked just fine.  Now trying to live with Ubuntu and only go back to windows when necessary.